# Auto clear dependent data validation in Google Sheets

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I have a Google sheet where I’m using a dependent drop down for users to select one option and then select a second option depending on their first choice.
Im doing this using the Index function on a separate tab where all my data is.

I’m trying to figure out a way to auto clear the second option when either the first choice is deleted or changed.

I feel like a script should be able to take care of this but im a novice when it comes to writing code and I can’t find an answer on the internet.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you provide a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on (free of sensitive information), clearly indicating the desired behaviour?

Comment: Absolutely. Here is the link to the sheet, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UYDa3qb_bm1V75u-1ddYQrfedTXH8ckrxY2vrZtwyMo/edit . It’s for fantasy baseball and the tab in question is Waiver Claims. I have that tab drawing data from another tab called Lists (which will normally be hidden). I added a roster to Tampa Bay so you could see how it works. I want to know if I can have the “Dropped” and “Injured List” automatically clear when someone clears out the “Owners” cell, in this case Tampa Bay

Comment: I have posted an answer explaining how this can be done. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks! I put that script in but got this error:   Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ ClearData.gs:2

Comment: This means you are trying to execute the function directly from the editor, so e is undefined. This is supposed to run whenever a user edits the spreadsheet, not via manual execution. But anyway, I modified this line so that it checks whether e exists and get the active range if that's not the case, so it can be executed directly too. Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: Hi, did this work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Issue:

You want to clear the cells in columns `I` and `J` whenever column `B` is edited.

#### Solution:

You could use a simple [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger for this. When you have an `onEdit` trigger, the corresponding function will fire every time a user edits a cell. In this case, you can do the following:

- Use the corresponding [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#edit) to check whether the edited cell is in column `B` from sheet `Waiver Claims`.
- If that's the case, clear the content from the desired cells using [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent).

#### Code snippet:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const range = e ? e.range : SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  const colIndex = range.getColumn();
  const rowIndex = range.getRow();
  if (rowIndex > 3 && colIndex === 2 && sheet.getName() === "Waiver Claims") {
    sheet.getRange(rowIndex,9,1,2).clearContent();
  }
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Simple triggers: onEdit(e)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite)

Comment: Thanks for the help! When I put that script in it gives me this error:                           
Error 
TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined
onEdit @ ClearData.gs:2

Comment: @ScottShimer This means you are trying to execute the function directly from the editor, so `e` is undefined. This is supposed to run whenever a user edits the spreadsheet, not via manual execution. But anyway, I modified this line so that it checks whether `e` exists and get the active range if that's not the case, so it can be executed directly too. Let me know if that works for you.